# Keep getting invalid expression errors

Tags: matlab, function, error-handling

I have this code, which is taken as an example from learning material.

```
function sum_out = sum_of_squares(2)
sum_out = 0;

for i = 1:n;
    sum_out + i*i;
end

end
```

However I cannot run it because I get this error message:

```
>> sum_of_squares
Error: File: sum_of_squares.m Line: 2 Column: 35
Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication operator, missing or
unbalanced delimiters, or other syntax error. To construct matrices, use
brackets instead of parentheses.
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The expression between parentheses in the `function` definition line should be the name of the parameter to the function, not a value. I think you mean:

```
function sum_out = sum_of_squares(n)
sum_out = 0;

for i = 1:n;
    sum_out + i*i;
end

end
```

Then, when you execute `sum_of_squares(2)`, inside the function the variable `n` will have the value 2.

More about defining functions [in the doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Answer (score 0):

After the answer above i corrected it as such

```
n=2
```

function sum_out = sum_of_squares(n)
sum_out = 0;

for i = 1:n;
sum_out + i*i;
end

end